# Is NSUserDefaults the right choice for this app idea in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a super simple app idea that I'm building out in order to get more practices at using Swift. I just want to ask if using NSUserDefaults is the most appropriate choice. All I will have is list of names with a number associated with each name that I will update (the number) from time to time. I was going to use a NSDictionary for the data.

I think Core Data is over kill for something like this.

I just wanted to get a 2nd opinion on my idea on how to save the data for this simple app.

Thanks

Comment: Save your NSDictionary in .plist file. Google for more details.

Comment: For fix number of records you can use .plist or `NSUserDefaults` . if your records will be increase then core data is preferable.

Comment: Or you can try writing to a simple txt file, one line per person, name string separated by a number, if you like.

Comment: Check out my answer, I think it should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserDefault. But If want to store an array or dictionary you have to do some extra work. [The documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:):

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

You can convert your `NSDictionary` to `NSData`, then save it to `NSUserDefault`.

```
// Convert the dictionary and store
var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourDict)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: yourKey)

// Retrieving the dictionary
var savedData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey(yourKey)
var dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedData)
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: There's no need to convert anything. NSDictionary is fine with a key-value pair that are both NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one NSDictionary that should be fine. NSUserDefaults is good for small things like that.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(**YOUR DICTIONARY**, forKey: **YOUR KEY**)
```